# which is the best way to autopost users wall

Tags: facebook, sdk

i wanna know which is the best way to autopost users wall without violation facebook  platform policy ?
My app was recently restricted because the message post was been autocompleted.
I make a new site, and without these will have no sense. I leaving this message, i will post just  : a photo caption , a title header,a simple desc and link and most will be posted in background (no visible on site) when a user is registered a new account. Apologize for my eng.

And if this it's impossible, all the popular games (angry birds, saga eclipse, etc...) how do that?

Comment: No popular games does that. Please show me an autoposted post that a popular game have done

Answer (score 0):

There is NO legal way to autopost on the user wall, every single post you make must be authorized by the user. And the message or caption always must be 100% user generated. You can read all about this in the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

This may be interesting for you though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph